# ChartJs Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I have data for different months as bellow

> Jan : [1,5,3]
>
> Feb : [10,5]
>
> Mar : [4,8]
>
> Apr : [7]
>
> May : [3,1,5,0,7]

And I want to generate bar chart as bellow

[image]

Right now, I have the following code and I would like to know how can I generate the bar chart as above image.

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
type: 'bar',
data: {
  labels: ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May'],
  datasets: [{
      data: [1,5,3],
      label: 'Jan',
      backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
    }
            , {
      data: [10,5],
      label: 'Feb',
      backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
    }, {
      data: [4,8],
      label: 'Mar',
      backgroundColor: "#4287f5",
    }
            , {
      data: [7],
      label: 'Apr',
      backgroundColor: "#23ebbc",
    }
            , {
      data: [3,1,5,0,7],
      label: 'May',
      backgroundColor: "#e63057",
    }
  ]
},
options: {
  title: {
    display: true,
    text: 'This is title'
  },
  backgroundColor:'#cfcfcf',
        scales: {
      xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
      yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
    }
}
```

});

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First data set is `[10,10,8,7,3]` which is the red, second is `[5,5,8,0,1]`, third `[3,0,0,0,5]`, fourth `[0,0,0,0,7]`

Of course, you must use your own skill to transform data sent by web services. But this is the final result you look for.

Comment: In my stacked bar chart, I have different expenses for each month as food, drinks,stationary,entertainment, travel and other. Is it possible to show those label with each expenses in above stacked bar chart?
ex: 
jan : food : 1 , stationary : 5, drinks : 1 |
feb : food : 10, other : 5 |
mar : drinks : 4, entertainment : 5 |

Comment: Pick one of examples that meet your needs https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/ . Also labels are controlled by you, you must construct your own label with the datas.

Answer (score 0):

I have only used ChartJS once but judging by what you want I would assume you create a bar type chart and add each of those data sets separate. for example, datasets:[{data:yourRedData}] then append that to the chart.

seams as though they do have an example of what you desire, https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/stacked.html

I checked the source code of the example to get a better understanding on how they achieved the results and here is what I found.

```
var barChartData = {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Dataset 1',
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor()
            ]
        }, {
            label: 'Dataset 2',
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor()
            ]
        }, {
            label: 'Dataset 3',
            backgroundColor: window.chartColors.green,
            data: [
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor(),
                randomScalingFactor()
            ]
        }]

    };
    window.onload = function() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
        window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: barChartData,
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked'
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answering. But in my situation number of data set  should equal to number of bars. I want to show each data set as a bar. thank you

Comment: @SandunHarshana you are preparing the `data` wrong. Each index of the data is a data for one month. In your case, your data should contains 5 elements, each.

Comment: @Thanh Actually that data coming from a web service. We have some expenses for each month and number of expenses are different for each month. I am going to show expenses for each month ( and want to show each expenses for a month in different colours for each bars) using stacked bar chart. Is it possible to show those data in stacked bar chart as I mentioned in question ? , thank you.

Comment: Seeing the example of the documentation above, I'd say yes. Now you have to transform your data into an acceptable format. From the example image you post, you need to prepare 4 dataset (because 4 different colors) for 5 months (size of array `data`)